# How to fix No route matches [GET] "/pages/send_form" routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am setting up so a user is able to send an email using the contact us form. I have created a file called "send_form" so once the submit button is clicked, the message automatically displays "Thanks for contacting us".

In the past, I have tried to include different routing in the routes.rb for example, "pages#send_form" and "contact#send_form".

```
# Example of regular route:
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get 'news' => 'pages#news'
  get 'show' => 'topics#index'
  get 'send_form' => 'pages#send_form'
  get 'new' => 'booking#new'
```

views/pages/contact.html:

```
<h1>Any enquiries:</h1>
<center><form name="htmlform" method="get" action="/pages/send_form">
<table width="700px">
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">Your Email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="message">Your Message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
  </div>
  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

views/pages/send_form

```
<h1>Thanks for contacting us,</h1>
```

I expect the output to be "Thanks for contacting us" once the submit button is clicked. However, I am receiving the error of "No route matches [GET] "/pages/send_form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `get 'send_form' => 'pages#send_form'` to `get 'pages/send_form' => 'pages#send_form'`.
Or instead change the action of your form to `action="/send_form"`